# Nuget copy file from packages folder to project directory

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have a nuget package that contains some dlls and a file "db.resources".
When I add the package to the project it references all the dlls but it does not copy the db.resources file to the project. (the file exists in the folder packages/myPackage next to all the dlls).
How do I configure nuget to copy that file to the project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @ivansystems, your link lead me to another link (https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package) wich helped me figure this out.
I was configuring the 'db.resources' file wrong. In my .nuspec file it was configured to go in the folder 'lib' instead of 'content'. Now every time I install the package in a project 'db.resources' is copied in the project folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually install the db.resources from the command line.. Here is a link that can help and give explanation http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/01/installing-nuget-packages-directly-from.html

Let me know if this helps